# 301 redirect directory within same domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

my client currently has WordPress installed in the root directory and a separate WP installation in a sub directory for a membership area.

She has moved the membership area to a new domain and now wants to delete the members directory from the original site.

However she wants all image links that were located in the members area to be redirected to where they are now located in the root directory of the original site.

For example:

Current path is

```
example.com/members/wp-content/uploads/year/month/imagename.jpg
```

New path will be

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/imagename.jpg
```

So all content after /uploads/ needs to be pointed away from /members/uploads/ to where it's now located.

Having searched this site and others, I've tried several different variations and nothing is working.

This is the last variation I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your help!

Here's a copy of the current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# block referer spam
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons\-for\-website\.com
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN PopUpBypass
# END PopUpBypass

#Use PHP 5.4
# Use PHP54 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php54/lib
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

SetEnvIfNoCase Via evil-spam-proxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-domain.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer evil-spam-keyword spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Via pinappleproxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer poker spammer=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spammer

<Files "xmlrpc.php">
Order Allow,Deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your rule this way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^members/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how that works out.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)  I've tried that but still not working :(  

I'm wondering if something is conflicting with it. Here's what's in the .htaccess file.  I'll add a copy to my post above so you can see it clearly

Comment: What exactly happens? I don't know what `still not working` means. What does it do or not do. Also clear your browser cache or try in another browser.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. When I input a url into my browser to an image on the server and include  /members/ in the path, I want it to redirect to the path without /members/ in it. Unfortunately it's not redirecting, I can still see /members/ in the path in my browser. Yes, I have been clearing my cache and trying it in two browsers.

Comment: are you sure it's reading your htaccess file? Is everything else definitely working?

Comment: Here's a url on the domain so you can see - http://thebusinesssuccessfactory.com/members/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo.png it should be redirecting to http://thebusinesssuccessfactory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo.png

Answer (score 0):

Inside `/members/.htaccess` try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ahhh so the .htaccess in the members directory is what may be causing the problem. I'm going to be deleting it, so hopefully things will start working ok when I do. Only one way to find out! haha. I'll update this thread afterwards.

Comment: You don't need to delete `/members/.htaccess` since it might be having some important directives for your website. Just place this rule in `/members/.htaccess` as **very first rule** to make it work

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough- the members area has been moved onto a new domain, therefore it no longer exists at all on the original domain. 

I want to catch any links that point to images that had been uploaded to the members area and redirect them to the image files now located in root uploads folders.

ie. old path:

example.com/members/wp-content/uploads/

redirects to: 

example.com/wp-content/uploads

Comment: Hmm in that case you can create an empty directory called `members/` and place above rule in `/members/.htaccess`

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.